# Splitting a column of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a column named Variable and some values associated with them:

```
Variable  Value
A D         5
A D         5
B D         5
B E         5
C E         5
C E         5
```

Where (A D),(B D),(B E),(C E) are names of some THING I'm analysing. How can I split my column into 2 separate columns with column 1 as a factor column:

```
Column1
A:2
B:2
C:2
```

and column 2 following a similar structure:

```
Column2
D:3
E:3
```

Comment: You need to have the same amount of rows in each column.  What should the third row be on the second one?  NA?  And are you beginning with just one column with values placed side-by-side?

Comment: I don't understand. I have my items with values associated with them. I want to differentiate between the items a bit more by separating the Variable column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the **Column1** and **Column2** have **different row numbers**, so I use **list** to storage the result.

```
data <- data.frame(
  Variable = c("A D", "A D", "B D", "B E", "C E", "C E"),
  Value = rep(5, 6)
)
split_var <- function(variable){
  return(strsplit(variable, " ")[[1]])
}
variable_mat <- t(apply(matrix(data[,1], ncol=1), 1, split_var))
Column1_table <- table(variable_mat[,1])
Column1 <- paste(names(Column1_table), Column1_table, sep = ":")

Column2_table <- table(variable_mat[,2])
Column2 <- paste(names(Column2_table), Column2_table, sep = ":")

result_list <- list(Column1 = Column1, Column2 = Column2)
```

And the result:

```
> result_list
$Column1
[1] "A:2" "B:2" "C:2"

$Column2
[1] "D:3" "E:3"
```